# Aligning HTML elements to the middle of the parent without JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I want to place a <div> in the middle of an element. Aligning it horizontally is easy, and of course the vertical alignment can be done with JS, but I'm sure that there's a better way of doing this with CSS. What's the trick?

P.S. I need this for an application with the HTML5 <canvas> element, so I don't mind if the solution only works in browsers that support canvas and in IE 7,8 (which support canvas when using a plugin).

---

*edit*: the height (and width) of the div **are** resizable in browsers that support the CSS3 property `resize`. However, I don't mind about it too much.

*another edit*: I also don't know the height of the div (even if it hasn't been resized).

---

## edit: see live demo 
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/md5WM/33/)

this example uses JS. *(Loktar - thanks for the link).*

---

`Thanks();`

Comment: Is the div you want to align vertically fixed height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `display:table`, `display:table-cell`, and `vertical-align:center` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m5sw2/) to center. It will adjust to fit content, but unfortunately the width will remain 100% of the container. You can see it used [here](http://playground.deaxon.com/)

Comment: With a small change to your idea - [I did it](http://jsfiddle.net/globalDeveloper/m5sw2/55/) ! It probably doesn't work in IE7, but that's pretty insignificant.

Answer (score 4):

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/jnNf4/1/)***

One way to align vertically is to set the `line-height` to the `height` of the container.

```
#parent{
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   line-height: 300px; 
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: You set it to `height`, not `height/2`

Comment: np. :) Nice solution btw, will have to remember this.

Answer (score 2):

If the element you want to align has a fixed size, give it *absolute position* and make its `top` and `left` 50%. Then subtract half its height for its `margin-top` and half its width for `margin-left`. *e.g.*

**html:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="alignedcontainer">content</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#alignedcontainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the element does not need to wrap, a quick and dirty way is to set the line height equal to the div height (assuming it's a static height).

Answer (score 1):

This works in Chrome

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #outer 
        {
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid #000; 
            width: 400px; 
            height: 400px; 
            margin: 20px; 
            padding: 20px;                 
            }
        #inner 
        {
            position:absolute; 
            top:25%; 
            right:25%; 
            bottom:25%; 
            left:25%;
            width: 200px; 
            height: 200px; 
            background-color: #ccc;                
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
</body>
```