# center a div in the middle of the screen IE v 6.0

Tags: css

I have a div which by pressing a button should appear in the center of the screen.
I use the following CSS code:

```
    #box {

    width: 490px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-245px;
    height: 200px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;
    background: #302d1a;
    border: 1px solid #313131;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    position:fixed ;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The code works fine in Opera Chrome Firefox , but it doesn't work in IE v 6.0 ?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean the div shows up, but in IE 6 it's not centered?

Comment: Yes, the div shows up but not in the middle of the screen.

Comment: IE 6 doesn't support position fixed:
http://www.caniuse.com/#search=fixed
Try to use position absolute instead.

Comment: There are many questions involving techniques for centering vertically. Have you tried using the `display:table-cell` technique? See: **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302304/aligning-html-elements-to-the-middle-of-the-parent-without-javascript/5303117)**

Comment: @Nathan that question is a bit different. That is about aligning to the center of an element. This is about a fixed centering on the entire page.

Comment: @Ktash Hmm, true, centering this way would require styling of the `body` and `html` element for the whole page to work. Which is probably not a viable option in this scenario...

Answer (score 0):

If #box is inside another container that has a specified width, this would probably work for you:

```
#box { 

    width: 490px; 
    left:50%; 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    height: 200px; 
    top:50%; 
    margin-top:-100px; 
    background: #302d1a; 
    border: 1px solid #313131; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 9999; 
}
```

I just added a margin-left and margin-right set to auto.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate position fixed using expressions in IE6, but as was said in the comments, position fixed does not work in IE6

```
#box {
    top: expression((document.clientHeight / 2) + document.body.scrollTop + "px");
    position: absolute;
}
```

Be sure to put this in a conditional comment for IE 6.